# Using Watir to interact with HTML 5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, watir

I am trying to automate testing of UI that relies on canvas for some elements, mainly graphs and such. What I want to do is somehow extract the values as they are shown to the user in the graph using Watir, the problem is that the values are only shown in a popup, that is added to the html when the user puts the mouse over in icon that is drawn in the canvas using gwt code.

Using firefox I can see that the mouse events in the canvas element contains the values I want (without having to actually hover the icons drawn by the Java code) and I could parse them in the ruby script if I could get at them. 
Is there anyway to fire the event and get the actual event details or payload using watir.

The code is behind a corporate firewall, so can't point anybody to it, but say for example I have this mouse event (in firebug console)

```
mousemove clientX=400, clientY=230
```

with the current target

```
canvas#indicators-result.MULTI_INDICATORS_TABLE
```

And if I click on that I can see an attribute d with a 2D array of the values I want to validate.
Is there anyway of getting that information

Thanks